# how to convert system type (C sharp) to java lang class

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

I am trying to use Java library inside Xamarin project through [binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/). I need to pass a C sharp class type as a parameter to a Java method.

`typeof()` method in C sharp doesn't work because the compiler compilations

> Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Type" to "Java.Lang.Class"

Is there any way to convert it correctly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to use `Java.Lang.Class.FromType(Type)` in Xamarin.

For example, your C sharp class could be `Car`

then call it as `Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Car))` in Xamarin